# Error 99 from published MVC project

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis

I have a web app written in ASP.NET MVC which usually works as it should, but upon submitting the first login page, I occasionally see the error page below. Nothing is logged in ELMAH, and a Google search has returned nothing. I've had similar results with both Chrome and Firefox. Anyone have any ideas what could be causing this?

[image: screen shot]

If I click on the 'Webmaster' mailto link, the email body is filled out with the following:

CacheHost: tx22rrpep37a
ErrPage: ERR_CONNECT_FAIL
Err: (99) Cannot assign requested address
TimeStamp: Sat, 01 Dec 2012 01:52:08 GMT

ClientIP: 10.5.0.99
ServerIP: benjineering.com

HTTP Request:
POST /cloud-chm/Account/Login?ReturnUrl=%2Fcloud-chm HTTP/1.1
Host: benjineering.com
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 488
Cache-Control: max-age=0
Origin: http://benjineering.com
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.11 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/23.0.1271.95 Safari/537.11
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Referer: http://benjineering.com/cloud-chm/Account/Login?ReturnUrl=%2fcloud-chm
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8
Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3
Cookie: _jsuid=782392611; ASP.NET_SessionId=i1u4twd1usymcgtppcejhsxt; __RequestVerificationToken_L2Nsb3VkLWNobQ2=F97jJ8pEE3oalgEJFpNCLMU68UE8nG2AdHeI_KDQSfiN2yOj0fV4-psVMtt59sDddJc4XdHM8DLppmdR-fen1xWHp4wkE22KwLaoCKYplWyrlBC3OmeClTcTTKXPdCTC_A-YEhEOVM6FO55fHIBCow2

Comment: The strange thing is, I just received the same error the first time I tried to submit this question. Maybe it's nothing to do with my project? It would be a coincidence though, because I've never seen the error before.

Comment: I'm now getting the same error page intermittently when I submit a form on other sites such as MyCareer and this one. I'm getting the impression that it has nothing to do with my site, but comes from either my router (an Android phone with a third party tethering app) or ISP.

Answer (score 1):

This looks like a customised error page for an error at web server or infrastructure level (ie. not the application). At face value, it looks as though the your logon url cannot be found, possibly to a resource being unavailable. What type of authentication does the application use? Does it rely on another server?

Are you in control of the hosting, or do you have a 3rd party provider? If the latter you might ask them for their interpretation of the error message.

I appreciate there's no answer here, but I hope the observations and questions might help you arrive at one.

Comment: Thanks Paul, it helps just to have a second pair of eyes.

Comment: It is hosted on a 3rd party server, and I've submitted a help ticket with them, awaiting a response. The application uses forms authentication, not changed much from the code which is automatically generated by Visual Studio, which uses a SQL database.

Comment: Could it be that the application web server is unable to contact the SQL Server? Is SQL Server hosted on a separate machine? 

From what you say, it sounds like an intermittent error. When it happens is the application able to deliver any other functionality that requires access to the database?

Comment: The server is on the same machine, it all comes good if I refresh a couple of times. I'm now not convinced it is related to my site (see above comment). Thanks for your help though!